# Android Library Module Conflict

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am opening my library module's activity in a sample application. everything works fine but when i enable flavours in my library module project than, i am unable to use library module activity. The activity class becomes unavailable to my sample application.

What is the actual problem and how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 3.0.0-alphaX gradle, the problem might be with a new change that is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_aware)

Basically, the library will now be aware of your app flavour and builtType and will try to use the same one.

You may need to set a default flavour, such as:

`flavorSelection 'shape', 'square'`

under `defaultConfig`

Comment: Hey @Allan, thanks for your support. But there is some mistakes in my implementation, i've resolved this problem after reworking on my implementation. :)